# Inner Join more than 2 tables (5 tables)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Before you guys send me to something else because there is already something like this answered. I don't quite understand the examples given there.

```
function joinBestelling (){

$sql =( "SELECT 
        artikel.artikelCode, 
        factuurregel.aantal 
    FROM artikel 
    INNER JOIN factuurregel 
    ON artikel.artikelCode = factuurregel.artikelCode");

 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

 $stmt->execute();

 $records = $stmt->fetchAll();

return $records;
}
```

so i have two tables now artikel and factuurregel how do i add like 3 more tables with info in the join ?

Comment: By adding additional ```join``` and ```on``` clauses after the ```on``` clause you have. One for each table you want to join.

Comment: What tables do you want to join? And with one row (mandatory) or more rows?

Comment: I should also read about the different JOIN methods like INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN

Comment: have you tried to google it

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the outher tables like the first one:

```
SELECT 
        artikel.artikelCode, 
        factuurregel.aantal 
    FROM artikel 
    INNER JOIN factuurregel 
    ON artikel.artikelCode = factuurregel.artikelCode
    INNER JOIN table3 on .....
    INNER JOIN table4 on .....
```

Hopefully that was your question

Comment: now i get an empty array back with the following:                         
    function joinBestelling (){
    
    $sql =( "SELECT 
            artikel.artikelCode, 
            factuurregel.aantal 
            FROM artikel 
            INNER JOIN factuurregel 
            ON artikel.artikelCode = factuurregel.artikelCode
            INNER JOIN klant ON klant.Voorletter
            INNER JOIN medewerker ON medewerker.voorLetters");

     $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

     $stmt->execute();

     $records = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $records;
    }

Comment: @NadalRahman I do not know your data, because you have not shown it. Maybe you use a left join for some tables if it is possible thta you have no entry in one of the tables

Answer (score -3):

```
function joinBestelling (){ 
   $sql =( "SELECT factuurregel.factuurNummer, factuurregel.artikelCode, factuurregel.aantal, factuurregel.prijs, factuur.factuurNummer, factuur.factuurDatum, factuur.klantCode, klant.klantCode, klant.voorLetter, klant.achterNaam, artikel.artikelCode, artikel.artikel, artikel.prijs FROM factuurregel JOIN factuur ON factuurregel.factuurNummer = factuur.factuurNummer JOIN klant ON factuur.klantCode = klant.klantCode JOIN artikel ON factuurregel.artikelCode = artikel.artikelCode");
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
   $records = $stmt->fetchAll();
   return $records;
}
```